# Android Studio/IntelliJ ADB Not found

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, adb, android-sdk-tools

I am having trouble connecting android device with IntelliJ or Android Studio. It was working fine but after I update the Android API Level to 29 I am seeing the issue.
When I am trying to connect an Android or Open  Device File Explorer, I am seeing the below error. I am using Intellij Ultimate 2019.3.3.

```
2020-03-26 12:07:41,510 [4502981]  ERROR - mpl.AdbDeviceFileSystemService - ADB not found 
java.lang.Throwable: ADB not found
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.adbimpl.AdbDeviceFileSystemService.start(AdbDeviceFileSystemService.java:111)
    at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.DeviceExplorerController.setup(DeviceExplorerController.java:138)
    at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.DeviceExplorerToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(DeviceExplorerToolWindowFactory.java:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.ensureContentInitialized(ToolWindowImpl.java:534)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.getContentManager(ToolWindowImpl.java:358)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.content.ContentTabLabel.contentManager(ContentTabLabel.java:356)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.content.ContentTabLabel.isSelected(ContentTabLabel.java:339)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.content.ContentTabLabel._getGraphics(ContentTabLabel.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.content.BaseLabel.paintComponent(BaseLabel.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.content.ContentTabLabel.paintComponent(ContentTabLabel.java:334)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.content.ToolWindowContentUi.paintChildren(ToolWindowContentUi.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowHeader.paintChildren(ToolWindowHeader.java:249)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1629)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1566)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1333)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:868)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:851)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:851)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:826)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:775)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1901)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

On running `echo $PATH` I am see this and I am able to run the adb command from command line:

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/nihardongara/Seller/member_mobile_rn_upgrade/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/nihardongara/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/bin:/Users/nihardongara/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.5/bin:/Users/nihardongara/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools
```

Comment: try using there 2 commands in terminal `adb kill-server`   and   `adb start-server`

Comment: tried it. Doesn't work.Still seeing the same

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Java SDK level to 1.8 fixed it surprisingly.

Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs -> Edit the Android SDK

[image]